# Options to store item clicks data for an e-commerce store

Tags: mysql

We have a eCommerce store which is growing at good pace. We recently started recording item "clicks" data. Since users click a lot, these data seems to be growing very fast. We have 40k clicks in last 10 days. This is not a good long term solution as this table is already taking more than 50% of the index space.

Which other solutions would be better equipped for this?

The potential use case for this is to enable some features in future - like showing users their click history and analytics.

Answer (score 1):

40k clicks per day is about 14.6 million clicks per year.

That is very feasible to store in MySQL.  You may want to partition the table to make it faster to get more recent data.  However, indexes might be sufficient.